# Observable Collection of Observable collections

Tags: c#

I want to generate observable collection of type string based on other observable collections.

I have a parent class that contains a property ID. From that class i create two children classes and then create two observable collections, each for one of the children classes. Now I want to create a collection that will only contain the IDs from both children observable collections. I know I can do that by adding the ID to the collection every time i add to the other collections, the problem is with removing. I use WPF DataGrid as the interface to Son and Daughter and want to be able to allow the user to delete inputs using the Delete key.

I have tried using a decostructor for both children components but removing them from the collection doesn't actually make the garbage collector dispose of them.

```cs
public class Father
{
        public Father()
        {
        }
        public string ID { get; set; }  
}

public class Son
{
    public Son()
    {
    }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}
public class Daughter
{
    public Daughter()
    {
    }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}



public class Main
{
    ObservableCollection<Daughter> daughters = new ObservableCollection<Daughter>();
    ObservableCollection<Son> sons = new ObservableCollection<Son>();

    ObservableCollection<string> IDs = ???


}
```

What i want to achieve is to have a collection that is always up to date with IDs from both Son and Daughter collections and want to avoid "recreating" the collection every time I add a new children instance.

Comment: Handle the CollectionChanged events on both `daughters` and `sons`. Define IDs as `List<String>`. In those handlers, set `IDs = daughters.Select(d => d.Prop2).Concat(sons.Select(s => s.Prop1)).ToList();`. I don't think you really need IDs to be an ObservableCollection. But if you do, call its Clear() method and write a loop to add the results of that `Concat()` call. In that case you would assign the results of the Concat() to a temp variable instead of to IDs itself.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thank you, I have managed to create a workaround, and just settled on adding new entries to the list on their creation and then rely on event from the other observable collection to remove it, when its done by user. Thank you for your help